# python checking crosswords from left to right

Tags: python-2.7

how do i make element of list join together and check if the elements make one of some specific words ? and remove every element that does not make any words and replacing them with a blank space. I am a beginner so go easy on me.

appreciate the help.

My Code:

```
def looking_word_left_to_right(the_list):
    for any_words in the_valid_words:
        for every in the_list:
            for letters_s in every:
                index_list=0
```

the valid words : aardvark
albatross
alligator
armadillo
barracuda
camel
caribou
cat
cattle
chamois
chicken
cod
deer
dinosaur
dog
dogfish
dotterel
dragonfly
eel
ferret
finch
fish
flamingo
fly
goldfinch
dragon
otter
ox
deer

the lists = ['e', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'z', 'a', 'g', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'e', 'n', 'b', 'n', 'd', 'o']
['d', 'e', 't', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'i', 'g', 'a', 't', 'o', 'r', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'o', 'l']
['m', 'e', 'z', 'n', 'a', 'c', 'a', 't', 't', 'l', 'e', 'e', 'b', 'l', 'r', 'c', 't', 'a']
['c', 'f', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'r', 'c', 'e', 's', 's', 's', 'a', 'd', 'l', 'r', 'i', 't', 'f']
['h', 'f', 't', 'r', 'a', 'r', 'r', 's', 's', 'o', 's', 'a', 'o', 'i', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'f']
['a', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'p', 'p', 'o', 'h', 's', 's', 'a', 'r', 'g', 'h', 'c', 'e', 'r', 'u']
['m', 'r', 'h', 'e', 'i', 'r', 'm', 'm', 'w', 'i', 'l', 'd', 'f', 'c', 'u', 'm', 'e', 'b']
['o', 'i', 'm', 'l', 't', 'a', 'a', 'i', 'r', 'f', 'o', 'v', 'i', 'n', 'd', 'a', 'l', 'b']
['i', 'g', 'l', 'a', 'l', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'o', 'e', 'a', 's', 'i', 'a', 'x', 'u', 'e']
['s', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'r', 'h', 'h', 'r', 't', 'y', 'l']
['r', 'l', 'a', 'h', 's', 'i', 'f', 'd', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'k', 'r', 'c', 't', 'l', 'a', 'i']
['a', 'r', 'e', 'o', 'g', 'o', 'l', 'd', 'f', 'i', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'e', 'f', 'n', 'n', 'd']
['d', 'm', 'n', 'e', 'e', 'p', 'o', 'l', 'e', 't', 'n', 'a', 'r', 'n', 't', 'a', 'd', 'o']
['d', 'i', 'n', 'o', 's', 'a', 'u', 'r', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'f', 'o', 'e', 'c', 'l', 'i', 'c']
['t', 'n', 'a', 'h', 'p', 'e', 'l', 'e', 'p', 'a', 'l', 'g', 'a', 'i', 'e', 'r', 'h', 'o']
['h', 'c', 'a', 'o', 'r', 'k', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'y', 'a', 't', 'r', 'm', 'o', 'a', 'c', 'r']
['f', 'l', 'a', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'o', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'f', 'l', 'o', 'e', 'c']
['h', 'a', 't', 'e', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'h', 'd', 'r', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'r', 'i', 'b', 'o', 'u']

```
my_str="ellezagchickenbndodetballigatoraaaolmeznacattleeblrctacfenarcesssadlritfhftrarrssosaoiarefaareppohssarghcerumrheirmmwildfcumeboimltaairfovindalbiglalobehoeasiaxuesabldinbbccrhhrtylrlahsifdlogkrctlaiareogoldfinchefnnddmneepoletnarntadodinosauroxofoeclictnahpelepalgaierhohcaorkcocyatrmoacrflamingoerefafloechateehchdracaribou"
def create_2d_list(N):
    output_list=[]
    counter=0
    for row in range(0,N):
        temp=[]
        for col in range(0,N):
            temp.append(my_str[counter])#you can add a charcter instead of counter
            counter=counter+1
        output_list.append(temp[:])
    return output_list

N=18

x=create_2d_list(N)

for row in range(0,N):
total=0
s="|"
for col in range(0,N):
    my_str="{0:2} ".format(x[row][col])
    s=s+my_str+"|"

    print "-"*(N*4+1)
   print s,
   print " "

the_valid_words=open("E:/asd/words.txt","r").readlines()

def list_duplicates_of(seq,item):
start_at = -1
locs = []
while True:
    try:
        loc = seq.index(item,start_at+1)
    except ValueError:
        break
    else:
        locs.append(loc)
        start_at = loc
return locs

def looking_word_left_to_right(the_list):
for any_words in the_valid_words:
    for every in the_list:

        for letters_s in every:
            index_list=0
```

Comment: Can you provide us an example of `the_valid_words`, and an example of `the_list`?

Comment: done, i just edited it .

Comment: if none of the words are found in the row is the row supposed to be all bank spaces?

Comment: yeah, if no characters make any of the valid words, leave blank spaces instead of characters , |"the_blank_space"|"the_blank_space"|"the_blank_space"|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting your rows to strings makes it easier to find your target words.  the_list needs to be a list of lists for this to work.

```
row_letters = [''.join(r) for r in the_lists]
words = 'aardvark albatross alligator armadillo barracuda camel caribou cat '
        'cattle chamois chicken cod deer dinosaur dog dogfish dotterel '
        'dragonfly eel ferret finch fish flamingo fly goldfinch dragon otter '
        'ox deer'.split()

for i, row in enumerate(row_letters[:]):
    for word in words:
        if word in row:
            wi = row.find(word)
            row_letters[i] = ' '*wi + word + ' '*(len(row) - wi - len(word))
    if ' ' not in row_letters[i]:  #works if word size < row size
        row_letters[i] = ' '*len(row)


>>> row_letters
['       chicken    ', '    alligator     ', '     cattle       ',
 '                  ', '                  ', '                  ', 
 '                  ', '                  ', '                  ', 
 '                  ', '                  ', '    goldfinch     ',
 '                  ', '        ox        ', '                  ', 
 '                  ', 'flamingo          ', '           caribou']

>>> new_the_list = [list(r) for r in row_letters]  # puts back to list format
```

Comment: its is already a list inside a list because its a part of a crossword code, i'll upload the whole code right now

Comment: Your list did not look like a list in a list though. The outer brackets and commas between lists were missing.

Comment: i just uploaded it, sorry man i'm a first year programmer and getting used to this because i just took the def functions two days ago and this is an assignment due tmw,

Comment: I see, since you are starting with a string, just break it into a list of strings, not a list of lists.  It is easier to search for strings in other strings.

Comment: okay list of strings, i think your code will do, and if i'm searching from up to down, the same thing ?